# Dummy Output on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I've been using 20.04 for a while now and sound was working (albeit clunky) until very recently.

Now I'm only getting `Dummy Output` on the available sound output. I've exhausted almost every similar post on the web and everything has failed; I've tried solutions related to: manually configuring `snd_hda_intel`, removing `pusleaudio`'s `conf` files, reinstalling `alsa` and other `alsa` counterparts.

Some diagnostics I've done: I've ran `alsa-info.sh` and the output can be found [here](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=4b6733d8cfddf71f9842557dbbef135e9c9f9e25).

Any help will really be appreciated! The sound issue is *REALLY* driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue last week and solved by adding just two lines.

open **/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf** using your preferred text editor. I'm using vim

> sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

after file opened add below line at the end.

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

and save the file.

Now open another file **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**

> sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

and add below line at the end of the file.

```
blacklist snd_soc_skl
```

save the file and reboot the system.

I hope it will work.